# iron-router render notFound template when route does not exist

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

If the data function returns a falsy value like null, the NotFound template will be rendered in my application. This works fine, but now I want also to render the NotFound template, if the route does not exist.

For instance:

```
this.route('settingsOverviewPage', {
        path: '/settings',
        data: function() { return Users.findOne(Meteor.userId()); },
        waitOn: function() {
            if (Meteor.userId()) {
                return Meteor.subscribe('ownUser', Meteor.userId());
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
```

If I use this route: `/settings12345` for instance, the browser reloads, but it renders the *last* route.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define a "catch-all" route like this :

```
this.route("notFound",{
  path:"*",
  template:"notFoundTemplate"
});
```

It is important that you define this route as the LAST one, otherwise it will catch valid URLs.